# How to access later page numbers using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I'm building a rails app that generates a PDF dynamically, based on user content. My setup is as follows:

`report` action, defined in my `Projects` controller:

```
def report
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        pdf = ReportPdf.new(arguments)
        send_data pdf.render, 
            filename: 'report.pdf', 
            type: 'application/pdf', 
            disposition: 'inline'
      end
    end
end
```

The controller calls my class `ReportPdf` defined in `app\pdfs\report_pdf.rb`, as follows:

```
    class ReportPdf < Prawn::Document
      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

      def initialize(arguments)
        super()
          chapter_1
          chapter_2 
          # etc...
      end

      def chapter1
        # lenght depends on user input 
      end

     def chapter2
        # lenght depends on user input 
     end 
     #etc..
   end
```

On the first page of my PDF (in `chapter_1`) I wish to print the total number of pages of the document.

```
text "This document contains #{n} pages"
```

`page_count` however only returns the number counting back from the current page.

How do I access the last page number from the first page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend getting all the user input first, then calculating number of pages. Right now you're be trying to stop a loop on a number you don't know yet.

### EXAMPLE

```
for pages in pdf do
   number_of_pages += 1
end
```

*At this point we don't know how many pages the PDF will have*

So I'd add a method before chapter one which gathers the input for the number of pages.